# Sample space/Event Cards questions

Tags: probability

I came across this question in a textbook that unfortunately doesn't supply answers for even-numbered exercises and I can't seem to get my head around it and find a reasonable approach. Could someone please explain how to get the answer and the notation that is required? Thanks in advance!

> *In an experiment, cards are drawn, one by one, at random and successively from an ordinary deck of $52$ cards. Let $A_n$ be the event that no face card or ace appears on the first $n − 1$ drawings, and the $nth$ draw is an ace. In terms of $A_n$’s, find an expression for the event that an ace appears before a face card,*
>
> *$(a)$ if the cards are drawn with replacement*
>
> *$(b)$ if they are drawn without replacement*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the answer should be the following. Let $E$ be the event an ace appears before a face card.

1. Without replacement: $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{37}A_n$ because if $E$ holds, either the ace have appeared in one of the first $36$ drawings (36 is the total number of cards that are neither face card nor aces) or it will definitely appear in the turn $37$.
2. With replacement: $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$. The difference here is that the number of drawings is not limited, it might happen (although it is extremely unlikely) that you never obtain neither aces nor face cards. However, if the event $E$ holds, that means that $A_n$ is satisfied for some $n$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand it now! 
Is it the use of $A_n$ that eliminates the possibility of drawing a face card at all? Assuming that we stop drawing cards after the first Ace is drawn.

Comment: If we assume that we stop after a first ace i drawn, then the answer is yes: $A_n$ exactly says that no face card have appeared yet.